# VM instances does not use the google cloud dns forwarder to resolve

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns, google-cloud-networking

i have setup my infra on GCP and created a VPC and firewall rules to allow outgoing 53 from inside my network to the outside.

i also setup a private dns zone in google cloud and added a dns forwarder ip (e.g. 192.168.1.1) to it. i also added the network that my vm is in to the dns zone allowed list .

now when i launch my VM and try to dig to test.mydomain.com it does not work, but when i put the ip mentioned above that i used as the dns forwarder in the /etc/resolve.conf the dig works ..

what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the resolution of [internal DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns) names is handled by the Instance metadata server (169.254.169.254)

If you change the name server configuration for your Instance, you might not be able to use internal DNS names. Any replacement of the name server software must support the Local Subnet Routes feature of RFC 3442.

Comment: i have opened a case with GCP to check with them why the GCP Cloud DNS is not forwarding requests to the destination IP .waiting for an answer

Comment: As you have already opened a case with GCP. Could you please provide the result that they give you?